Help needed on complex number.
Question
$z$ and $w$ are two complex numbers such that $\left|z+w \right|=\left|z-w \right|$.
(a) Show that $zw^*+z^*w=0$.
(b) Hence, deduce that $\frac{iz}{w}$ is a real number.
My attempt
(a) I managed to show that $zw^*+z^*w=0$ as follows:
$$\left|z+w \right|=\left|z-w \right|$$
$$\left|z+w \right|^2=\left|z-w \right|^2$$
$$\left(z+w\right)\left(z+w\right)^*=\left(z-w\right)\left(z-w\right)^*$$
$$zz^*+zw^*+z^*w+ww^*=zz^*-zw^*-z^*w+ww^*$$
$$zw^*+z^*w=0$$
(b) I am totally lost on this. I thought of using the results in (a) to help me but it seems that I am not getting anywhere. Here is my attempt:
$$zw^*+z^*w=0$$
$$\frac{izw^*}{ww^*}+\frac{iz^*w}{ww^*}=0$$
$$\frac{izw^*}{ww^*}=-\frac{iz^*w}{ww^*}$$
$$\frac{izw^*}{ww^*}=-\frac{iz^*w}{\left|w\right|^2}$$
And I am lost from this point onwards. It seems to me that I am not getting anywhere in proving that $\frac{iz}{w}$ is a real number. May I know how should I proceed?
Thank you very much in advance.

Your attempt is almost there. With the assumption that $w\ne 0$, using $i^* = -i$, $$\begin{align*}
\frac{izw^}{ww^} &= -\frac{iz^w}{ww^}\
\frac {iz}w &= \frac{i^* z^}{w^} = \left(\frac {iz}w\right)^*
\end{align*}$$

@peterwhy Thank you for your response. However, I do not understand how $\frac{iz}{w}=\left( \frac{iz}{w} \right)^* $ proves that $\frac{iz}{w}$ is real.

What complex numbers have their conjugate equal to itself? What would $\frac {iz}w = \left(\frac {iz}w\right)^*$ imply on $\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac {iz}w\right)$?

@peterwhy does it mean that it has to be imaginary?

We have that for $w\neq 0$
$$zw^*+z^*w=0 \iff \frac z w=-\frac{z^*}{ w^*}$$
then
$$\left(\frac z w\right)^*=\frac{z^*}{ w^*}=-\frac z w$$
that is $\frac z w$ is purely immaginary then $\frac {iz} w$ is real.

Let $~a~$ denote $~zw^* \implies a^* = z^*w.~$
This implies that $~a + a^* = 0.$
Let $~b,c \in \Bbb{R}~$ be chosen so that $~a = b + ic.~$
Then, since $~a + a^* = 0,~$ you have that 
$(b + ic) + (b - ic) = 0 \implies 2b = 0 \implies b = 0.$
Therefore $~a = zw^*~$ must be a purely imaginary number.
Now, note that
$$\frac{z}{w} = \frac{zw^*}{ww^*}. \tag1 $$
In the fraction on the RHS of (1) above, the numerator is a purely imaginary number, and the denominator is a real number.  Therefore, the entire fraction is an imaginary number.
Therefore, $~\dfrac{iz}{w}~$ must be a real number.

Lets start from
$$zw^* + z^*w = 0.$$
Divide by $ww^*$ under the assumption $w \neq 0$
$$\frac{z}{w} + \frac{z^*}{w^*} = 0 $$
We therefore have
$$\frac{z}{w} + (\frac{z}{w})^* = 2Re(\frac{z}{w}) = 0 $$
The quantity $\frac{z}{w}$ is hence fully imaginary implying that
$$ i\cdot \frac{z}{w} = - Im(\frac{z}{w}) $$ is a real number.

How did you get $\frac{z}{w}+\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^*=2Re\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)$?

This is a standard formula which can be proven by simply writing the complex number as a sum of real and imaginary part. The following holds: $$ z + z^* =2Re(z)$$ and $$ z - z^* = 2i Im(z)$$. Let me prove the first statement as requested. We have $z = Re(z) + iIm(z)$ and therefore the sum equates to $$ Re(z) + iIm(z) + (Re(z) - iIm(z)) = 2Re(z)$$ for arbitrary complex number z.

From $|z+w|^2 = (z+w)^*(z+w) = |z-w|^2$ we get $\operatorname{re} z^*w = \operatorname{re} zw^* = 0$, which is equivalent to (a). If $w \ne 0$, which seems to be assumed in (b), we see that $\operatorname{re} {zw^* \over |w|^2} = \operatorname{re} {z \over w} = 0$, and so ${z \over w}$ is purely imaginary from which (b) follows.
